# LESS / Is it possible to extend the nearest ancestor that is nested itself?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to expect this CSS output:

```
.a .b { color: green }
.a .c, .b { color: green }
```

from this LESS code:

```
.a {
     .b {
        color: green;
       .c {
         &:extend(.b);
       }
     }
}
```

In one sentence: can we extend the nearest ancestor that is nested itself?

Comment: There is no `.b` to extend, since `:extend` will only match the full contextual selector. It **will** match something if you use `:extend(.a .b)` since that selector exists (but you won't obtain the output you suggested since that would require `.c` to be under `.a` and not `.b`.)

Comment: Could you write an answer in order to close the post? :) I will validate it.

Comment: Ok! I'll also detail it a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `.b` to extend, since `:extend` will only match the full contextual selector and a `.b` doesn't exist (only `.a .b` exists). So `:extend(.b)` will have no effect.

It *will* match something if you use `:extend(.a .b)` since that selector exists. This:

```
.a {
     .b {
        color: green;
       .c {
         &:extend(.a .b);
       }
     }
}
```

will result in:

```
.a .b,
.a .b .c {
  color: green;
}
```

But you won't obtain the output you suggested since that would require `.c` to be under `.a` and not under `.b`. With this:

```
.a {
     .b {
        color: green;
     }
    .c {
         &:extend(.a .b);
     }
}
```

You would obtain the result below, which is closer to what you expect:

```
.a .b,
.a .c {
  color: green;
}
```

To obtain the result you expect, you just have to add this (at top-level):

```
.b:extend(.a .b){}
```